# The maximum product of adjacent elements in java

Tags: java, arrays

i am trying to print The maximum product of adjacent elements in an array but i am getting an error in my program:

**if input is** [2, 5, 8, 9, 6]

**then desired output is** : 72

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int Product=0;
        int len = sc.nextInt();
        int[] arr = new int[len];
        for(int i=0; i < len; i++){
            arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i<len-1; i++){
            Product = arr[i]*arr[i+1];
           int Nproduct = arr[i+1]*arr[i+2];
           {
               if(Product<Nproduct){
                   Product = Nproduct;
               }
           }
        }
        System.out.println(Product);
    }
}
```

please help me where i am wrong. i am new here so please ignore my mistakes or edit if possible

Comment: Describe exactly what you problem is, logic, exception....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code needs some changes

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int Product=0;
        int len = sc.nextInt();
        int[] arr = new int[len];
        for(int i=0; i < len; i++){
            arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i<len-1; i++){
            if (arr[i]*arr[i+1]>Product){
                Product=arr[i]*arr[i+1]; 
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Product);
    }
}
```

for reference click here : [GFG Problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-product-of-4-adjacent-elements-in-matrix/)

Answer (score 3):

**There is some logical error as well as Run time error** in your code.

#### Take a Look at modified version of your code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int Product=0;
        int len = sc.nextInt();
        int[] arr = new int[len];
        for(int i=0; i < len; i++){
            arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i<len-1; i++){
            if (arr[i]*arr[i+1]>Product){
                Product=arr[i]*arr[i+1]; // update Product only if we get greater product
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Product);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change second loop `for (int i = 0; i<len-1; i++)` to `for (int i = 0; i<len-2; i++)` to prevent running out of upper array's bound